# how can i call selected item into model when i click on button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can i call selected item into model when i click on button in react? I tried this code but it gave me same output for every buttons...

More Details

```
            <div class="modal fade" tabIndex="-1" id="exampleModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Details</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" onClick={this.update}>
                            <h4>{this.state.data.name}</h4>
                            <h5>Region :- {this.props.item.region}</h5>
                            <h6>Capital :-{this.props.item.capital}</h6> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            {/* <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
handleItem(capital){
console.log(capital)
}
render(){
return(
 <div class="modal fade" tabIndex="-1" id="exampleModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Details</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" onClick={this.update}>
                            <h4>{this.state.data.name}</h4>
                            <h5>Region :- {this.props.item.region}</h5>
                            <h6>Capital :-{this.props.item.capital}</h6> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
  onClick={this.handleItem.bind(this,this.props.item?.capital)}   >Close</button>
                            {/* <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
            }
```

i think you are missing onclick event where you can get the value

Comment: i put onclick event but i want when i click on the button that particular item will show in modal body....

Comment: you are already getting only 2 item instead of array sill you please elaborate what do you mean by specific

Comment: first thing i fetch data from api and display in bootstrap card also put button(more detail) for every card...  second thing now when i click on button(more detail) i want or show that selected particular card data into modal...

Comment: ok first store data in any state then send the id through onclick and then filtered item from all data with th help f that particular id or you can also use index

Comment: can you give me example?